# Can the citus data coordiator and worker node be on the same machine?

Tags: postgresql, citus

Reading [citus data's tutorial](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.0/get_started/tutorials.html), I was wondering if in a small cluster, I can have the coordinator and one of the workers installed on the same machine?

I am testing this on a small scale cluster with two worker nodes to do the computing job. And I'd like to use as few machines as possible.

So far, I only have experience with installing one PostgreSQL server instance in each machine (Ubuntu Linux). In this setting, does the coordinator have to be on its own machine?

(This is with PostgreSQL 14 and citus 11.0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can add a new postgresql instance running on a different data path and port-number.

You could even put all your instances onto a single machine - but do not expect good performance in this setup.